# Chrome hack to search bookmarks inside specific folder/folders only?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm a bookmarks hoarder. I have around 10,000 bookmarks in Google Chrome, nicely organized in folders and sub-folders.

Sometimes I want to search through the bookmarks in a specific folder. Unfortunately the Google Chrome team hasn't come up with anything to help with this yet. Currently, bookmarks search searches through all folders and subfolders.

Anyone know of a hack that can enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Bookmark Manager and Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager-and-view/mnhojcjhcilkgkmijhphlbmghmmdhlfg).
Just right-click on the folder, and search.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily a hack, but came up when I googled search folders for bookmarks or something like that. An extension exists called [Atomic Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/atomic-bookmarks/fkbecffhfgdpiigmkgljmfgnejmhfejh) which is a bookmarks menu that allows you to search through folders. It is kind of old and isn't a hack, but its a bit easier to execute than a hack too. It also still searches through subfolders, but at least it doesn't search in folders above the current one.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I had downloaded Atomic in the past but hadn't realized that it offered the feature of not searching in folders above the current one. I don't remember removing it from my Chrome Extensions and it's odd that [it doesn't show up when searched in the Chrome App Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/atomic%20bookmarks?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher&_category=extensions). Considering that Chrome bookmarks can be exported to just a simple html file, I'm hoping someone comes up with some sort of parser to do more advanced power searching on them.

Comment: it seems Atomic has been replaced by Bookmarks Manager Plus -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager-plus/pfbeenngglcojppheoegjjjomfkejibg?hl=en

Comment: +1 confirmed. atomic bookmarks is 404 in chrome store. bookmarks manager plus installs and (though not really intuitive) can show you search results by folder.