# Search Chrome bookmarks only within specific folder

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

I want to search Chrome bookmarks only within a specific folder, and **re-organize search results**.

```
e.g. 
1) go to bookmarks
2) go to folder "Business"
3) search for "Trump"
4) select all search results
5) move results to folder "Politics"
```

The current Chrome Bookmarks allows to easily move search results from one folder to another, but it offers no way to search only within a specific folder, and offers no way to know in which folder the search results are located.

I know of two Chrome extensions that allow to search within specific folders: [Atomic Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/atomic-bookmarks/fkbecffhfgdpiigmkgljmfgnejmhfejh) and [Everymark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/everymark/ccgmhgakppaknnnnbgkmpdlnpjokhcpb), yet neither allows to move search results from folder to folder. Moving search results from folder to folder with these extensions requires opening all search results one by one and re-bookmarking. Horribly inefficient.

This [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/1192461/chrome-hack-to-search-bookmarks-inside-specific-folder-folders-only) covers the same issue, yet the answer suggests Atomic Bookmarks, which as explained above does not offer the feature to re-organize bookmarks.

This is such a basic and necessary feature.

Would anyone know how to hack Google Chrome to achieve this, or of any other extensions I missed?